# Writing a specific SQL Group By Statement

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have a table which I have screenshotted and uploaded the image here:

[image]

I need to create an sql query that counts the number of orders with the following pizza quantities: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and above 6.

I've tried a number of SQL statements but haven't found the right one.

My current attempt is

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectPizza %>" 
            SelectCommand="Select '1' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 1 
            UNION ALL
            Select '2' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 2
            UNION ALL
            Select '3' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 3
            UNION ALL
            Select '4' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 4
            UNION ALL
            Select '5' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 5
            UNION ALL
            Select '6' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity = 6
            UNION ALL
            Select 'Above 7' AS Caption, Count(quantity) AS Count FROM orders WHERE quantity > 7">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

but it isn't going successful.

I want to make a chart too, but even if my sql statement were successful I'm not sure what I'd enter for my X and Y value members.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Yet again another **Not ASP Classic** question, the `<asp:SqlDataSource` is a big give-away!

Answer (score 0):

This will break out your quantities the way you want and then group the counts of quantities by 1-7.  I didn't use the case in the group by because it is not allowed in many databases.

```
Select o.quantity AS Caption, Count(o.quantity) AS Count 
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN quantity < 7 THEN Quantity ELSE 7 END) quantity from orders) o 
group by o.quantity
```

Comment: better if you explain it further

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close, but will label all 7+ quantities as '7'

```
select  case when quantity < 7 then quantity else 7 end,
        count(*)
from    orders
group by case when quantity < 7 then quantity else 7 end
```

To get the 7+ labeling correct, would need to know exactly which variant of SQL you were using